# Failing UDP broadcast from local network with a python script

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I have a windows computer on a small local network, containing an LTE router, a managed switch, said windows box and GNSS device broadcasting position data via UDP. The GNSS is set to broadcast on 255.255.255.255 : 5017

I also have a windows device with two ethernet interfaces, on which I am running the following python script to try and receive those UDP messages and write them to a file.

```
import os
import socket
import pynmea2
import datetime
from io import StringIO

path = "C:\\DataGoesHere\\"

IP = " "
port = 5017

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(5)
sock.bind((IP,port))

while True:
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    todayfile = f'{today}_GNSS.csv'
    

    pathfile = os.sep.join([path, todayfile])
    if not os.path.isfile(pathfile):
        with open(pathfile, 'w') as file:
            print('Created file: {}'.format(pathfile))
            #pass

    with open(pathfile, 'a') as file:
        while today==datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"):
            try:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                print(pynmea2.parse(data.decode()))
                file.write(data.decode())
            except socket.timeout:
                print("Didn't receive data! [Timeout]")
```

So far I have always had the socket time out. I am able to see the UDP packets using wireshark, so they are being sent and arriving. I have ensured there's a firewall rule allowing UDP packets on port 5017, and I have also tested temporarily turning off the windows firewall in case that was still somehow an issue. The script also got the socket.timeout error even with the firewall turned off.

At this point I'm about at the end of my knowledge of how to troubleshoot, and would appreciate any fixes or diagnostic tips.

Comment: Please forget about broadcast; it is being deprecated and does not exist in IPv6, so you application cannot be ported. Modern applications use multicast. Broadcast interrupts everything on the LAN, including things like printers and routers that have no interest in your broadcast. Multicast only interrupts interested devices.

Comment: please post your comment as an answer and accept it so Stack Overflow doesn't keep pinging people about this unanswered question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RonMaupin this gave me a good steer. The device that was broadcasting just has the option to use TCP instead, so I switched to sending data on TCP and switched socket types, and now everything works. So it didn't actually solve the problem I'm asking about here, but probably I'm doing things in a better way overall.